# Android - how can I dynamically load drawables (pictures)? Names not known until run-time

Tags: android

I've searched Google and this website many times, but can not find a solution to my question.

First, I understand, you can load images using something like:

```
int image = R.drawable.icon; (assuming there's a file called 'icon.png')
```

and I've read about, and tried using:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("resname", "restype", com.example.whatever);
```

But, here's what I'm unable to do:
I want to be able to have pictures in the /res/drawable folder (I believe that's the correct folder), WITHOUT KNOWING ANY OF THE NAMES OF THE FILES, and load them dynamically - at run-time.

One (of the many) things I've tried is (something like):

```
int[] images = new int[numberOfImages];
for( 0 to numberOfImages )
{
    images[i] = 
        getResources().getIdentifier("resname", "restype", com.example.whatever);
}
```

This returns 0 EVERY TIME, so it's not going to work

I'd like to get the name and integer identifier for every picture in the /res/drawables folder.  Can this be done WITHOUT KNOWING ANY FILE NAMES?

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------

[adding this after the question was resolved to help anyone that may run into the same issue in the future.  It just shows that it does in fact work.]

```
    Class resources = R.drawable.class;
    Field[] fields = resources.getFields();
    String[] imageName = new String[fields.length];     
    int index = 0;
    for( Field field : fields )
    {
        imageName[index] = field.getName();
        index++;
    }

    int result = 
            getResources().getIdentifier(imageName[10], "drawable", "com.example.name");
```

Comment: Drawables are compiled resources, you won't be able to add something to drawable folder at runtime

Comment: Maybe I mis-stated myself. I don't want to add to the folder, I want to dynamically READ FROM the folder, without knowing file names before hand. I just want to load all pictures without calling them out by name. I want to be able to add pictures to the folder while the program is NOT RUNNING, and not have to change any code for the program to read them in - that's my goal.

Comment: The code you added works great! If only I just don't understand how it works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you have to do it, use reflection :)

```
Class resources = R.drawable.class;
Field[] fields = resources.getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    System.out.println(field.getName());
}
```

However, in a way, you are still hard-coding stuff, since you will only be putting a fixed set of drawables in your app. :)

Comment: what you're saying is to have: getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", com.example.whatever);

is that correct?  I believe I still will need to know each file name doing it that way.  I want to be able to not know ANY file name and loop through all files.

Comment: So, is it possible to do this without explicitly stating file names in the arguments for 'getIdentifer()'?

Comment: Well, Not directly, but you could have an array of strings somewhere (may be strings.xml), compare the runtime image name first with this string array, and if you find a match, get the resource id for that image name. Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, but that still involves hard coding names (into the array of strings), that's what I'm trying to avoid.  I've got the names in an array in my code, but I don't want hard coded file names ANYWHERE in the code.  I just want to say, "load ALL images that are in /res/drawable into this array".

Comment: YES! that does exactly what I want! Reflection mixed with the previously mentioned method. I remember seeing something about reflection at some point, but for some reason I never tried it. I picked up Android a little over a week ago, so these concepts are still new to me. If anyone comes here and is wondering how to achieve what I was trying, I posted an example at the bottom of my original question. Thank you again for the help, and sticking with my thread. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in the comments, if you want to add files to that folder after the app is installed you'll have to use a private folder. [Data storage documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Then use a service to download images and add them to the private folder.

If you want the user to download the app with some preloaded images and you don't want to wait for the service run for the time to download the initial set of images, you can always send some images in the `/res/raw` folder and in the first time your app runs, copy these to your private folder.

Comment: Point taken about adding images.  I really hadn't thought of that.  As of now, I'm just trying to get familiar with Android, so I'm just using the emulator and my own phone to run apps.  Thank you for the tip, I'm sure that will save me some headache in the future.