# how to include images into an android project  best  possible manner?

Tags: android, android-layout

My android app is basically a simple one where there is one listview with 40 list items. And each of those items when clicked leads one to an image. so there are 40 images.

I can always of-course place those images in the res/drawable folder and refer to them directly  from my java file in which case there will be hardcoding done

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.day1);
.
.
.
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.day3);
.
.
```

.
etc.

Is there anyway (by storing the names of the images in an xml for example) to programatically retrieve the image names from folder and display them ?

Comment: Hello Look at this problem 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776575/android-how-can-i-dynamically-load-drawables-pictures-names-not-known-until

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("day" + i,
    "id", getPackageName());
```

where i is your index

```
img.setImageResource(resID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic bitmap object using resource.

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/"+"test"+index+".png");
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Used same name of image like, image1,image2...
call using for loop or index..

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

I'd place the images in the res/drawable folder as you said, but wouldn't call them like you said; too much work! Try creating an array "Images", filled with a for loop where you add on each position something like:

```
for (i;i<x;i++)   //Where x is the number of images you use
     Images[i] = "R.drawable.day"+String.valueOf(i);
     // Even you could try with:
     // Images[i]="img.setImageResource(R.drawable.day"+String.valueOf(i)+")";
```

Like this, you just have to call images[i] to call image "i"

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple manner to do this is like this:
You place your images in res/drawable, name all using a certain pattern (for instance: img1, img2, img3 ... ) and after that you load them dynamically using a pattern for names like this:

```
String imageName =IMAGE_PATTERN+id;
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,null,getPackageName());
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imageResource));
```

where
    `IMAGE_PATTERN` may be something like "image" or "img" or whatever you used to name your files :)

good luck,
Arkde