# Fast way to import code for drawable

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have more than 2k pictures in my drawable folder and I was wondering if there is a way to import code automatically for all the images , so I don't have to write this 2k times or to change the number 2k times.

```
int[] photos={R.drawable.im1, R.drawable.im2,.....,R.drawable.im2000)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776575/android-how-can-i-dynamically-load-drawables-pictures-names-not-known-until

Comment: Why not simply generate the code for it?